# FFmpeg pipe input, error while transcoding from WebM to MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, webm, screencast

I am trying to record a video from pipe input using FFMPEG. The pipe input is in WebM format i.e. the video codec is VP8 and the audio codec is OPUS. I am able to save the output video in the WebM format using FFMPEG without any issue. But when I am trying to save it in MP4 format, I am not getting the desired output. Though there are no errors while saving, the output file shows an error with description " This file contains no playable streams!."

These are the options for successfully recording in the WebM format.

```
    '-loglevel', 'debug', '-protocol_whitelist', 'pipe,udp,rtp', 
'-fflags', '+genpts', '-i', 'pipe:0', '-map', '0:v:0', '-c:v', 
'copy', '-map', '0:a:0', '-strict', '-2', '-c:a', 'copy', '-flags',
 '+global_header', '-f', 'webm', 'output.webm'
```

Here are my ffmpeg options for recording in the MP4 format.

```
    '-thread_queue_size', '4096', '-r', '25', '-i', 'pipe:0', 
    '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'veryFast', '-pix_fmt', 'yuvj420p', 
    '-acodec', 'aac', "output.mp4"
```

Console output after executing this command as a subprocess

```
> ffmpeg::process::data [data:'  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 
31.100\n' + '  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100\n' + '  
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100\n' + '  libavdevice    58. 
 8.100 / 58.  8.100\n' + '  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100\n'
 + '  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0\n' + '  libswscale 
     5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100\n' + '  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.
  5.100\n' + '  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100\n'] +1ms
> 
> ffmpeg ffmpeg::process::data [data:"Input #0, matroska,webm, from
> 'pipe:0':\n" + '  Metadata:\n' + '    encoder         : Chrome\n' + ' 
> Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A\n' + '    Stream
> #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)\n' + ' 
   Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1920x950, SAR 1:1
> DAR 192:95, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)\n' + '   
> Metadata:\n' + '      alpha_mode      : 1\n'] +1s
> 
> 
>  ffmpeg::process::data [data:'Stream mapping:\n' + '  Stream #0:1 ->
> #0:0 (vp8 (native) -> h264 (libx264))\n' + '  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 
(opus (native) -> aac (native))\n'] +1ms
> 
>    ffmpeg::process::data [data:'[swscaler @ 0x55a63050ddc0] deprecated
> pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly\n'] +23ms
> 
>   ffmpeg::process::data [data:'[libx264 @ 0x55a630489980] using
> SAR=1/1\n'] +10ms
> 
>   ffmpeg::process::data [data:'[libx264 @ 0x55a630489980] using cpu
> capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2\n'] +0ms
> 
>   ffmpeg::process::data [data:'[libx264 @ 0x55a630489980] profile
> High, level 4.0\n'] +8ms
> 
>   ffmpeg::process::data [data:'[libx264 @ 0x55a630489980] 264 - core
> 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 -
> http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1
> deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
> mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
> deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=18
> lookahead_threads=6 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
> bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
> b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250
> keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf
> mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
> aq=1:1.00\n'] +1ms
> 
>   ffmpeg::process::data [data:"Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':\n" + '
> Metadata:\n' + '    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100\n' + '    Stream
> #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), 
yuvj420p(pc), 1920x950 [SAR 1:1 DAR 192:95], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
> (default)\n' + '    Metadata:\n' + '      alpha_mode      : 1\n' + '  
> encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264\n' + '    Side data:\n' + '   
> cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1\n' + '   
> Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz,
> stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)\n' + '    Metadata:\n' + '     
> encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac\n'] +0ms
> 
> ffmpeg::process::data [data:'frame=   45 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      
> 0kB time=00:00:01.87 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=3.48x    \r'] +505ms
> 
> ffmpeg::process::data [data:'frame=   61 fps= 56 q=28.0 size=      
> 0kB time=00:00:02.41 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=2.22x    \r'] +564ms
> 
> ffmpeg::process::data [data:'frame=   76 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=      
> 0kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.81x    \r'] +492ms
```

I have a doubt on this output as it may have been causing the issue.

```
ffmpeg::process::data [data:'[swscaler @ 0x55a63050ddc0] deprecated
 pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly\n'] +23ms
```

I hope I have provided enough information about the issue I am facing. Please ask for any other information needed to understand the issue correctly.

I am sure that I am missing some ffmpeg options which is causing this issue. But I am not able to identify them! Any help in correcting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the raw ffmpeg log rather than script captured version? It's impossible to read and make sense out of it.

Comment: @kesh sorry for a delayed response.I don't have the raw ffmpeg output. I am running the ffmpeg commands as a subprocess inside a recording application I am building using nodejs. Is there a way I can capture the raw ffmpeg output from the subprocess?

Comment: I think the key is *not* to capture the stderr. So, the ffmpeg stderr goes straight to the console, where you are running the node.js.

Comment: Now, you gave me a fresh eyes to reread your question, I may have an idea (and your log may not tell us). How are you terminating the ffmpeg child process in node.js? Most importantly, are you closing the `stdin` then waiting for ffmpeg to complete its task?

Comment: No, I am not waiting for FFMPEG to complete it's task! Can that be the issue?  I am killing the ffmpeg subprocess 1st and then closing the stdin after that.

Comment: 100%. I'm putting together an answer with the explanation

Answer (score 0):

- Most **H.264** decoders usually expect **YUV420p** pixel format.
- You do not tell FFmpeg the **input format** of media data from the pipe.

Try as:

```
'-thread_queue_size', '4096', '-f', 'webm', '-r', '25', '-i', 'pipe:0', 
'-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'veryFast', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 
'-acodec', 'aac', '-movflags', '+faststart', "output.mp4"
```

Comment: I tried your suggested option. The error is still the same. I have added the ffmpeg options I am currently using for successfully recording in the WebM format. Can you suggest changes needed to capture in the MP4 format?

Comment: See if the edit, with added `-f webm`, helps FFmpeg to make a playable video.

Answer (score 0):

If you are piping data to `ffmpeg` process, always close the `stdin` first then wait for the `ffmpeg` process to complete on its own. This is absolutely critical especially for the MP4 format, but it is a good practice in general.

The one of the primary differences between MP4 and MKV is that MP4 stores its stream info (aka MOOV packet) at the **end of the file** by default. So, if you kill the ffmpeg prematurely (e.g., right after writing the last frame to the pipe) you are not giving ffmpeg a chance to write the MOOV packet, which results in unusable file.

Comment: I tried today by closing the stdin first and then waiting for the process to complete. But still the result is the same. After checking the mp4 file size, I realized that ffmpeg may not have recorded any streams at all! the file size shows 48B and it doesn't contain any streams of video or audio.  I doubt that ffmpeg may have dropped all packets without storing anything. This line is very common through out the log. Can this be the cause of any problem?

 'cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)\n'

Comment: Because you're not filtering, the warning usually points to corrupted input file/stream with inconsistent frame timestamps. That being said, what happens if you drop `-r 25` input option? This framerate may be different from the actual framerate and forcing it could screw up the timestamps.